# lwjgl 2 controller not initialized error?

Tags: java, input, controller, lwjgl

I have been recently watching a tutorial on how to get controller input in lwjgl then a problem occurred so I made a new project and put in the exact code that he had letter by letter and then the same problem occurred. 
The error that i am getting is that first off lwjgl is saying it cant be initialized and java is saying that there is a class not found exception?

Here is my code:

```
package simple;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controller;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controllers;

public class ControllerInput {

    static Controller controller;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            Controllers.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Controllers.poll();

        for(int i = 0;i<Controllers.getControllerCount(); i++){
            controller = Controllers.getController(i);
            System.out.println(controller.getName());
        }


    }

}
```

(i have tried putting `Controllers.destroy()` at the end but that doesnt work)

here is my error:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Failed to initialise controllers
    at org.lwjgl.input.Controllers.create(Controllers.java:86)
    at simple.ControllerInput.main(ControllerInput.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      net/java/games/input/ControllerEnvironment
    at org.lwjgl.input.Controllers.create(Controllers.java:69)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to use *LWJGL2* legacy API with *LWJGL3*. Download and add to your classpath [LWJGL2's jar](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/download.php).

*LWJGL3's* input handling works [differently via GLFW](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.3-Input-handling-with-GLFW)

Comment: in lwjgl 2 there isnt a <code>Controllers</code> class even though there is a <code>Controller</code> class so im now not fully sure what to do. also i was actually using lwjgl 2 in the first place

Comment: There should be, according to the [javadoc](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Controllers.html). Did you include all the jars under lwjgl-2.9.3/jar folder? There should be a `jinput.jar`, which contains the missing ControllerEnvironment class.